# Using keybinding to make sprite continue to move and Snake body

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint, key-bindings

It's the same game that I'm working on and I've come to a problem that I can't understand again. I'm using Key Bindings to move my sprite and it's working great! but since it's a snake game I need the sprite to keep moving without stopping and change direction and keep moving after the player types a key.  I know it's possible with KeyListener, but I really don't want to have to change my program entirely. I just need to know what code needs to change, if possible.

On top of that I'm also working on two arrays for the x and y co-ordinates for the snake body so that squares will follow behind the head, but I can't get it to paint. and how to display an integer for the score.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Snake2 extends JFrame {

 /* Sprite: snake head co-ordinates */
 int x = 400;
 int y = 450;
 int width = 10;
 int height = 10;

 /* Sprite: snake body */
 int length = 0;
 ArrayList <Integer> bodyX = new ArrayList <Integer>();
 ArrayList <Integer> bodyY = new ArrayList <Integer>();

 /* Score */
 int point = 0;

/* Sprite: mouse co-ordinates */
Random rand = new Random();
int addx = (rand.nextInt(10))*10;
int addy = (rand.nextInt(10))*10;
int mx = ((rand.nextInt(5)+1)*100) + addx;
int my = ((rand.nextInt(6)+2)*100) + addy;

DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

public Snake2() {

addMouseListener(new MouseListener());
System.out.print(mx + " " + my);

/* move snake up */
Action upAction = new AbstractAction(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    y -=10;

    if (y >= my && y <= my+9 && x >= mx && x <= mx+9)
    {
      addx = (rand.nextInt(10))*10;
      addy = (rand.nextInt(10))*10;
      mx = ((rand.nextInt(5)+1)*100) + addx;
      my = ((rand.nextInt(6)+1)*100) + addy;
      point += 100;
      length++;
      bodyY.add(0, y);
    }

    if (y <99)
    {
       new GameOver();
       dispose();
    }
    drawPanel.repaint();
  }
};

/* move snake down */
Action downAction = new AbstractAction(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     y +=10;

     if (y >= my && y <= my+9 && x >= mx && x <= mx+9)
     {
       addx = (rand.nextInt(10))*10;
       addy = (rand.nextInt(10))*10;
       mx = ((rand.nextInt(5)+1)*100) + addx;
       my = ((rand.nextInt(6)+1)*100) + addy;
       point += 100;
       length++;
       bodyY.add(0, y);
     }

     if (y > 799)
     {
       new GameOver();
       dispose();
     }
     drawPanel.repaint();
   }
};

/* move snake left */
Action leftAction = new AbstractAction(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     x -=10;

     if (x >= mx && x <= mx+9 && y >= my && y <= my+9)
     {
       addx = (rand.nextInt(10))*10;
       addy = (rand.nextInt(10))*10;
       mx = ((rand.nextInt(5)+1)*100) + addx;
       my = ((rand.nextInt(6)+1)*100) + addy;
       point += 100;
       length++;
       bodyX.add(0, x);
     }

     if (x <99)
     {
       new GameOver();
       dispose();
     }
     drawPanel.repaint();
   }
};

/* move snake right */
Action rightAction = new AbstractAction(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    x +=10;

    if (x >= mx && x <= mx+9 && y >= my && y <= my+9)
    {
       addx = (rand.nextInt(10))*10;
       addy = (rand.nextInt(10))*10;
       mx = ((rand.nextInt(5)+1)*100) + addx;
       my = ((rand.nextInt(6)+1)*100) + addy;
       point += 100;
       length++;
       bodyX.add(0, x);
    }

    if (x > 699)
    {
      new GameOver();
      dispose();
    }
    drawPanel.repaint();
  }
};

InputMap inputMap = drawPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap actionMap = drawPanel.getActionMap();

inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "rightAction");
actionMap.put("rightAction", rightAction);

inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "leftAction");
actionMap.put("leftAction", leftAction);

inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "downAction");
actionMap.put("downAction", downAction);

inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "upAction");
actionMap.put("upAction", upAction);

add(drawPanel);

pack();
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setVisible(true);

}//Snake2()

private class GameOver extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JLabel answer = new JLabel("");
JPanel pane = new JPanel(); // create pane object
JButton pressme = new JButton("Quit");
JButton replay = new JButton("Replay?");
GameOver()   // the constructor
{
  super("Game Over"); setBounds(100,100,300,200);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  Container con = this.getContentPane(); // inherit main frame
  con.add(pane); pressme.setMnemonic('Q'); // associate hotkey
  pressme.addActionListener(this);   // register button listener
  replay.addActionListener(this);
  pane.add(answer); pane.add(pressme); pane.add(replay); pressme.requestFocus();
  answer.setText("You Lose");
  setVisible(true); // make frame visible
}//GameOver()

// here is the basic event handler
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
  Object source = event.getSource();
  if (source == pressme)
    System.exit(0);
  if (source == replay)
  {
    dispose();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    new Snake2();
  }
});
  }
}//actionPreformed

}//GameOver


private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

  super.paintComponent(g);

  Font ith = new Font("Ithornît", Font.BOLD, 78);

        /* Background: Snake */
  g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
  g.setColor(Color.gray);
        g.fillRect(100,100,600,700); 
  g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(99,99,601,701);

        g.drawString("Quit",102,86);
        g.drawRect(100,70,30,20);
        g.drawString("Score: ", 602, 86);

        g.setFont(ith);
        g.drawString("SNAKE",350,60);

              /* Sprite: Mouse */
  g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(mx, my, width, height);
        //System.out.print(mx + " " + my);

        /* Sprite: Snake Body */
        if (length != 0){
        for(int i = 0; i >= length; i++)
        {
  g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
        g.fillRect(bodyX.get(i), bodyY.get(i), width, height);
        }
        }

        /* Sprite: Snake head */
  g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

  }//Paint Component

  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  return new Dimension(800, 850);
  }//Dimension

}//DrawPanel

public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
    new Snake2();
    }
    });
  }// main

}//Snake Class


/* Tracks where mouse is clicked */
class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
  if (me.getX() >= 101 && me.getX() <= 131 && me.getY() >= 94 && me.getY() <= 115){
  System.exit(0);
}

String str="Mouse Released at "+me.getX()+","+me.getY();
System.out.println(str);
}
}//MouseAdapter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*but since it's a snake game I need the sprite to keep moving without stopping"*

You need to use a `javax.swing.Timer`. The basic constructor is like this

```
Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)  // delay is in milliseconds
```

A basic implementation would be something like this

```
Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
    }
});
timer.start();
```

Basically what the timer does, is fire an `ActionEvent` every so many milliseconds. This is how you work animation with swing. So without you pressing any keys, the sprite will move by itself.  It works pretty much like a button does. When you press a button an event is fired. But in the case of the timer, the timer is the one that fires the event. You can specify any `delay` you want. You many even want to change the duration dynamically when a certain level is reached. `timer.setDelay(someInt)`

---

**UPDATE**

I made very few changes to your current code. I did pretty much what I stated in the comment below

> Ok so I thought about it, and I would do something like this: Have a direction variable. For the actions, all you should do is change the direction. In the timer actionPerformed thats where all you logic should go. Check for the direction. If if equals "left" then continue going left like you would on a key press. And so on

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Snake2 extends JFrame {

    String direction = "right";

    //String duration = 

    /* Sprite: snake head co-ordinates */
    int x = 400;
    int y = 450;
    int width = 10;
    int height = 10;

    /* Sprite: snake body */
    int length = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> bodyX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> bodyY = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    /* Score */
    int point = 0;

    /* Sprite: mouse co-ordinates */
    Random rand = new Random();
    int addx = (rand.nextInt(10)) * 10;
    int addy = (rand.nextInt(10)) * 10;
    int mx = ((rand.nextInt(5) + 1) * 100) + addx;
    int my = ((rand.nextInt(6) + 2) * 100) + addy;

    DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
    Timer timer;
    public Snake2() {

        addMouseListener(new MouseListener());

        timer = new Timer(50, new TimerListener());     ////////////// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< TIMER
        timer.start();
        System.out.print(mx + " " + my);

        /* move snake up */
        Action upAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                direction = "up";                       ////////////// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< direction only change
            }
        };

        /* move snake down */
        Action downAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                direction = "down";
            }
        };

        /* move snake left */
        Action leftAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                direction = "left";
            }
        };

        /* move snake right */
        Action rightAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                direction = "right";
            }
        };

        InputMap inputMap = drawPanel
                .getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = drawPanel.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "rightAction");
        actionMap.put("rightAction", rightAction);

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "leftAction");
        actionMap.put("leftAction", leftAction);

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "downAction");
        actionMap.put("downAction", downAction);

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "upAction");
        actionMap.put("upAction", upAction);

        add(drawPanel);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }// Snake2()

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                /////////////////// <<<<<<<<<<<<<< All logic here
            if ("right".equals(direction)) { 
                x += 10;

                if (x >= mx && x <= mx + 9 && y >= my && y <= my + 9) {
                    addx = (rand.nextInt(10)) * 10;
                    addy = (rand.nextInt(10)) * 10;
                    mx = ((rand.nextInt(5) + 1) * 100) + addx;
                    my = ((rand.nextInt(6) + 1) * 100) + addy;
                    point += 100;
                    length++;
                    bodyX.add(0, x);
                }

                if (x > 699) {
                    new GameOver();
                    dispose();
                }
            } else if ("left".equals(direction)) {
                x -= 10;

                if (x >= mx && x <= mx + 9 && y >= my && y <= my + 9) {
                    addx = (rand.nextInt(10)) * 10;
                    addy = (rand.nextInt(10)) * 10;
                    mx = ((rand.nextInt(5) + 1) * 100) + addx;
                    my = ((rand.nextInt(6) + 1) * 100) + addy;
                    point += 100;
                    length++;
                    bodyX.add(0, x);
                }

                if (x < 99) {
                    new GameOver();
                    dispose();
                }
            } else if ("up".equals(direction)) {
                y -= 10;

                if (y >= my && y <= my + 9 && x >= mx && x <= mx + 9) {
                    addx = (rand.nextInt(10)) * 10;
                    addy = (rand.nextInt(10)) * 10;
                    mx = ((rand.nextInt(5) + 1) * 100) + addx;
                    my = ((rand.nextInt(6) + 1) * 100) + addy;
                    point += 100;
                    length++;
                    bodyY.add(0, y);
                }

                if (y < 99) {
                    new GameOver();
                    dispose();
                }


            } else if ("down".equals(direction)) {
                y += 10;

                if (y >= my && y <= my + 9 && x >= mx && x <= mx + 9) {
                    addx = (rand.nextInt(10)) * 10;
                    addy = (rand.nextInt(10)) * 10;
                    mx = ((rand.nextInt(5) + 1) * 100) + addx;
                    my = ((rand.nextInt(6) + 1) * 100) + addy;
                    point += 100;
                    length++;
                    bodyY.add(0, y);
                }

                if (y > 799) {
                    new GameOver();
                    dispose();
                }
            } 
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }
    }

    private class GameOver extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        JLabel answer = new JLabel("");
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(); // create pane object
        JButton pressme = new JButton("Quit");
        JButton replay = new JButton("Replay?");

        GameOver() // the constructor
        {

            super("Game Over");
            timer.stop();                                           ////////////////////// <<<<<<<<<< Stop TIMER
            setBounds(100, 100, 300, 200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Container con = this.getContentPane(); // inherit main frame
            con.add(pane);
            pressme.setMnemonic('Q'); // associate hotkey
            pressme.addActionListener(this); // register button listener
            replay.addActionListener(this);
            pane.add(answer);
            pane.add(pressme);
            pane.add(replay);
            pressme.requestFocus();
            answer.setText("You Lose");
            setVisible(true); // make frame visible
        }// GameOver()

        // here is the basic event handler
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (source == pressme)
                System.exit(0);
            if (source == replay) {
                dispose();
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        new Snake2();
                    }
                });
            }
        }// actionPreformed

    }// GameOver

    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Font ith = new Font("Ithornît", Font.BOLD, 78);

            /* Background: Snake */
            g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(100, 100, 600, 700);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawRect(99, 99, 601, 701);

            g.drawString("Quit", 102, 86);
            g.drawRect(100, 70, 30, 20);
            g.drawString("Score: ", 602, 86);

            g.setFont(ith);
            g.drawString("SNAKE", 350, 60);

            /* Sprite: Mouse */
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(mx, my, width, height);
            // System.out.print(mx + " " + my);

            /* Sprite: Snake Body */
            if (length != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i >= length; i++) {
                    g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
                    g.fillRect(bodyX.get(i), bodyY.get(i), width, height);
                }
            }

            /* Sprite: Snake head */
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

        }// Paint Component

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 850);
        }// Dimension

    }// DrawPanel

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Snake2();
            }
        });
    }// main

}// Snake Class

/* Tracks where mouse is clicked */
class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        if (me.getX() >= 101 && me.getX() <= 131 && me.getY() >= 94
                && me.getY() <= 115) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String str = "Mouse Released at " + me.getX() + "," + me.getY();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}// MouseAdapter
```

Comment: Where would it go in the code? would it replace AbstractAction?

Comment: You just need it in the constructor. I'll not really sure how your program works, so I don't want to offer too much advice with your code. I don't want to cause you any headaches.

Comment: Ok so I thought about it, and I would do something like this: Have a `direction` variable. For the actions, all you should do is change the direction. In the timer actionPerformed thats where all you logic should go. Check for the `direction`. If if equals "left" then continue going left like you would on a key press. And so on

Comment: See my **UPDATE**. You'll in the comments what I changed.